# OutOfRangeError : FIFOQueue 'batch/fifo_queue' in tf.train.batch

Tags: python, queue, fifo, tensorflow

I want to solve this problem.
I checked `num_epochs=None` of `tf.train.slice_input_producer` and I reduced batch_size 64 to 16.
However, OutOfRangeError does not disappear. I tried everything(On stackoverflow about 'OutOfRange, FIFOQueie, insufficient elements, train.batch, slice_input_producer'... If you know about solving this problem, please let me know.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import re
from datetime import datetime

from datetime import timedelta
from nets import PAM_Cnn, FD_Cnn
import load_jpeg_with_tensorflow

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
FLAGS.height = 250
FLAGS.width = 250
FLAGS.num_classes = 2
FLAGS.batch_size = 16

######################################################## Load Data ########################################################
main_dir = './data/LFWdata/LFW_train/'
log_dir = 'tmp/PAM/'

num_classes = 2 # Number of bubbles x 2

# batch_img, batch_label = load_jpeg_with_tensorflow.read_data_batch(train_dir, 'trainImageList.csv', height, width,
#                                                                    num_channels, batch_size=batch_size)

######################################################## Placeholder Variable ########################################################

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, FLAGS.height, FLAGS.width, 3], name='Input')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='Label')
Y_cls = tf.argmax(Y, dimension=1)

image_batch, label_batch, file_batch = load_jpeg_with_tensorflow.read_data_batch(main_dir+'trainImageList.csv', FLAGS.height, FLAGS.width, FLAGS.batch_size)

######################################################## Training Process ########################################################

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
prediction = FD_Cnn.build_model(X, keep_prob)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=Y))
tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(loss)

validate_image_batch, validate_label_batch, validate_file_batch = load_jpeg_with_tensorflow.read_data_batch(main_dir+'testImageList.csv', FLAGS.height, FLAGS.width, FLAGS.batch_size)
label_max = tf.argmax(Y, 1)
pre_max = tf.argmax(prediction, 1)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

startTime = datetime.now()
iteration = 20

summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
######################################################## TensorFlow Run ########################################################
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir, sess.graph)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in range(iteration):
        images_, labels_ = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])
        # images_ = image_batch
        # labels_ = label_batch
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X : images_, Y : labels_, keep_prob:0.5})

        if i % 10 == 0:
            now = datetime.now() - startTime
            print('## time:', now, ' steps:', i)

            rt = sess.run([label_max, pre_max, loss, accuracy], feed_dict={X : images_,
                                                                           Y : labels_,
                                                                           keep_prob : 1.0})
            print('Prediction loss:', rt[2], ' accuracy:', rt[3])
            # validation steps
            validate_images_, validate_labels_ = sess.run([validate_image_batch, validate_label_batch])
            rv = sess.run([label_max, pre_max, loss, accuracy], feed_dict={X: validate_images_,
                                                                           Y: validate_labels_,
                                                                           keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('Validation loss:', rv[2], ' accuracy:', rv[3])
            if (rv[3] > 0.9):
                break
            # validation accuracy
            summary_str = sess.run(summary, feed_dict={X: validate_images_,
                                                       Y: validate_labels_,
                                                       keep_prob: 1.0})
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
            summary_writer.flush()

        saver.save(sess, 'face_recog')  # save session
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    print('finish')
```

'load_jpeg_with_tensorflow.py' is below.

```
def get_input_queue(csv_file_name, num_epochs=None):
    train_images = []
    train_labels = []
    for line in open(csv_file_name, 'r'):
        cols = re.split(',|\n', line)
        train_images.append(cols[0])                                
        train_labels.append([float(cols[1])])
        # train_labels.append([float(cols[1]), float(cols[2])])
    print([train_images, train_labels])
    print("Number of images :", len(train_images))
    input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([train_images, train_labels], num_epochs=num_epochs)         # you should small num_epoch
                                                                                                                            # batch_size x
    return input_queue

def read_data(input_queue):
    image_file = input_queue[0]
    label = input_queue[1]

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(image_file), channels=3)

    return image, label, image_file

def read_data_batch(csv_file_name, height, width, batch_size):
    input_queue = get_input_queue(csv_file_name)
    image, label, file_name = read_data(input_queue)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

    batch_image, batch_label, batch_file = tf.train.batch([image, label, file_name], batch_size=batch_size)                 # add allow_smaller_final_batch=True
    batch_file = tf.reshape(batch_file, [batch_size,1])

    return batch_image, batch_label, batch_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I applied your solution, but it was not working. Why did you suggest setting absolute path? @IshantMrinal

Comment: I solved the problem!!! If you undergo same problem like me, you'd better check hidden layer input/output of your network. Of course your memory too.